# Why wont my graphs plot?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

f [x_] := (x + ln (x) - 3)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]

This is my first time using wolfram and I don't see why my graph always comes out empty with no plots. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mathematica is absolutely FANATIC about correct capitalization and correct spelling and correct use of () versus {} versus [] and those all mean completely different things to Mathematica.  Try f[x_]:=x+Log[x]-3; and you should find joy. If you always check the help pages for function names and capitalization that should help in the future.

Comment: Cross-posting is rather frowned upon in the SE multiverse ... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113614/graph-not-plotting-any-points

Comment: the other newbie gotcha with mathematica is it typically doesn't throw syntax errors for such things. Here it is patiently waiting for you to define the new symbol `ln` you invented.